# Biztalk: Nested Flat File Schema

Tags: xml, mapping, schema, biztalk

[I have these two tables that I wish to create a nested XML schema out of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjisC.png)

I want the schema to look something like:

```
<PERSON ID="1" FN="F1" LN="L1">
  <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="11"/>
  <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="12"/>
</PERSON>
<PERSON ID="2" FN="F2" LN="L2">
  <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="21"/>
  <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="22"/>
  <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="23"/>
</PERSON>
```

I call some SQL to get the data from the tables. 
One way I have tried is using an inner join on the "ID" field and the other way is using a stored procedure to return two sets of data, one for each table. The issue I am having in both ways is how do I map it to the above structure?

I end up getting one DETAIL record per PERSON record (PERSON repeats)
or I get all DETAIL records per PERSON record (ID no longer matches).

Comment: What did the SQL look like when you tried using an inner join? Also, I assume that the ID attributes should be ID="2" in the PERSON element with ID="2" ?

Answer (score 1):

Using FOR XML AUTO:

```sql
SELECT PERSON.ID, PERSON.FN, PERSON.LN, DETAIL.ID, DETAIL.NUM
FROM PERSON
JOIN DETAIL ON PERSON.ID = DETAIL.ID
FOR XML AUTO
```

Using FOR XML PATH:

```sql
SELECT p.ID '@ID', p.FN '@FN', p.LN '@LN', 
    (
        SELECT d.ID '@ID', d.NUM '@NUM'
        FROM DETAIL d
        WHERE p.ID = d.ID
        FOR XML PATH('DETAIL'), TYPE
    )
FROM PERSON p
FOR XML PATH('PERSON')
```

both will produce this:

```
<PERSON ID="1" FN="F1" LN="L1">
  <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="11" />
  <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="12" />
</PERSON>
<PERSON ID="2" FN="F2" LN="L2">
  <DETAIL ID="2" NUM="21" />
  <DETAIL ID="2" NUM="22" />
  <DETAIL ID="2" NUM="23" />
</PERSON>
```

Comment: So I am using DB2. So I have updated the SQL to return XML CLOB. Two rows, one for each PERSON and each with the appropriate number of DETAIL elements. But now the output from BizTalk reads the quotes as &quot; , the < as %lt; etc

How do I fix that?

Comment: `SELECT XML2CLOB(  
XMLELEMENT(NAME "PERSON",  
        XMLATTRIBUTES(ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME),  
        XMLAGG(  
            XMLELEMENT(NAME "DETAILS",  
                XMLATTRIBUTES(ID, NUM))  
            ORDER BY NUM)  
    ))  
    FROM PERSON INNER JOIN DETAIL  
 ON PERSON.ID = DETAIL.ID  
 GROUP BY PERSON.ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME;`

Comment: @MohammadZeni If you have extra details to a question use the edit button to edit your question rather than doing it in comments. If it is a new question then post a new question and add a link to this one if it is relevant to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this sql:

```
SELECT
ID AS '@ID',
FN AS '@FN',
LN AS '@LN',
(
SELECT ID AS '@ID', NUM AS '@NUM' FROM Table_2 WHERE table_2.ID = dbo.Table_1.ID FOR XML PATH('DETAIL') ,TYPE 
) AS 'details'
FROM dbo.Table_1
FOR XML PATH('PERSON')
```

You will get some xml content like below:

```
<PERSON ID="1" FN="F1" LN="L1">
  <details>
    <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="11" />
    <DETAIL ID="1" NUM="12" />
  </details>
</PERSON>
<PERSON ID="2" FN="F2" LN="L2">
  <details>
    <DETAIL ID="2" NUM="21" />
    <DETAIL ID="2" NUM="22" />
    <DETAIL ID="2" NUM="23" />
  </details>
</PERSON>
```

Comment: Leaving out the `AS 'details'` alias will make it look like the example structure in the question.